# XPath not getting any node

Tags: xml, xaml, xpath

I am trying to use XAML to read a XML file and show it on an app. This is my XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO8859-1" ?>
<CATALOG>
  <PLANT>
    <COMMON>Bloodroot</COMMON>
    <BOTANICAL>Sanguinaria canadensis</BOTANICAL>
    <ZONE>4</ZONE>
    <LIGHT>Sun</LIGHT>
    <PRICE>$2.44</PRICE>
    <AVAILABILITY>031599</AVAILABILITY>
  </PLANT>

  <PLANT>
    <COMMON>Columbine</COMMON>
    <BOTANICAL>Aquilegia canadensis</BOTANICAL>
    <ZONE>3</ZONE>
    <LIGHT>Shade</LIGHT>
    <PRICE>$9.37</PRICE>
    <AVAILABILITY>030699</AVAILABILITY>
 </PLANT>
```

Here I need to only display the content of COMMON where LIGHT = Sun

I tried this but it isn't working

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="CatalogusDataSource" Source="Data\catalogus.xml" XPath="CATALOG"/>
<DataTemplate x:Key="nameItemTemplate">
     <Label Content="{Binding XPath=*}"/>
</DataTemplate>
</Grid.Resources>

....

<ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
        <ListBox Name="ListBoxSchaduw"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CatalogusDataSource}, 
            XPath=/CATALOG/PLANT[PRICE\=\Sun]/COMMON}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource nameItemTemplate}" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you want to select the `COMMON` element where `LIGHT` is `'Sun'`, but your XPath is filtering by `PRICE`, and instead of the string value `'Sun'` you have an unquoted `Sun` which will be evaluated as if you were comparing an element called `Sun`.

Change the XPath to:

```
/CATALOG/PLANT[LIGHT='Sun']/COMMON
```

Comment: Congrats on your (imminent) XPath tag gold badge.

Comment: Thanks for putting me over the top!

Comment: I am getting the error now "The member "/CATALOG/PLANT[LIGHT" is not recognized or is not accessible." I always keep getting that error when i add '' around Sun.

Comment: Sounds like you might be having trouble balancing quotes. If you are inside an expression wrapping with double quotes, use single quotes for string values and vice versa.

Comment: Found the problem. /CATALOG/PLANT[LIGHT\=\'Sun\']

Comment: It was important to add the "\" charachter for the = and ''